# Sort WordPress Meta Field By Date Using WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I have posts with meta data that I want to sort by 'LiveStreamDate'. Format of meta field is: yyyy/mm/dd.

My current code below:

```
$recent = new WP_Query('cat='.$spcatid.'&paged=' . $paged); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
$tmpLiveTime = get_post_custom_values("LiveStreamTime");
$tmpLiveDate = get_post_custom_values("LiveStreamDate");
$tmpLiveCompetition = get_post_custom_values("LiveStreamCompetition");
$tmpLiveMatch = get_post_custom_values("LiveStreamMatch");
```

NORMAL LOOP STUFF HERE

Any ideas? I have looked through the WP_QUERY examples using meta fields and values - but how to construct the query (or add another query) to end up with data sorted by meta field by value of it's date?

Cheers
BK

Answer (score 2):

You can use the follow example:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_filter_posts_orderby' );
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'LiveStreamDate',
    'cat' => $spcatid,
    'paged' => $paged,
) );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_filter_posts_orderby' );

function my_filter_posts_orderby( $orderby )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value DESC, ' . $orderby;
    return $orderby;
}

while($query->have_posts()) { 
$query->the_post();
echo get_post_custom_values("LiveStreamDate");
}
```

The list of possible parameters are in WordPress file

> /wp-includes/query.php

inside this function:

```
/**
     * Fills in the query variables, which do not exist within the parameter.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $array Defined query variables.
     * @return array Complete query variables with undefined ones filled in empty.
     */
    function fill_query_vars($array) {
        $keys = array(
            'error'
            , 'm'
            , 'p'
            , 'post_parent'
            , 'subpost'
            , 'subpost_id'
            , 'attachment'
            , 'attachment_id'
            , 'name'
            , 'static'
```

(...)

Comment: You can add a filter for a Category name like this:
`$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'LiveStreamDate',
    'category_name' => 'Uncategorized',
) );`

or by ID like:

`$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'LiveStreamDate',
    'cat' => '138',
) );`

I update the reply.

Comment: hi works a treat! thanks...only problem now is that it is displaying duplicate post titles...any quick way to kill these?

Comment: Do you have Posts with the same title (and wants to avoid show them) or appears duplicated Posts data? Could you tell me more information because I'm testing and can't reproduce the problem.